# Updating [code of] web application without terminating/restarting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, web-deployment

I'm pretty confused on a best practice for how to do this and I cannot find any information, since I don't know if this has a specific name or not.

What is the best way to update a web application without having to close the site, copy new files, and restart the web server - be it RoR, Apache or what have you.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Use Unicorn to serve your site. One of its features is ability to deploy without losing connections. No downtime.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, ```puma```, ```thin``` and ```passenger enterprise``` also can be used for zero downtime deployments :)

Comment: @freemanoid: right. I forgot to add "for example". I don't know about passenger, though. It used to harshly kill client connections. That's why I migrated to unicorn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Sergio a good webserver to use would be Unicorn. Another thing to look into would be Capistrano, which is a deployment tool that uses a deployment process with easy rollbacks and will only switch to the new code if it's actually succeeded deployment.

Capistrano: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano
Unicorn: http://unicorn.bogomips.org/
(And a good post about the zero downtime deployments: http://ariejan.net/2011/09/14/lighting-fast-zero-downtime-deployments-with-git-capistrano-nginx-and-unicorn/)